# Identify numbers in mixed formats within a string in C

Tags: c, string, character

I have the following string:

```
 char *line; 
 char temp_line;
```

After some processing my pointer `line` pointing to `temp_line` contains the following string:

```
 "H2 + CH = CO2      4.00e-003     3.00e10     43.00"
```

I need a routine which can identify the three numbers you see. I can always assume there will be three different numbers. But **I cannot assume**  that all three numbers are given in exponential form.

What is the best way to achieve this in C?

Is there a way to let C read the line reversely, and instruct it to extract the last three figures of that line?

Comment: scanf() might be sufficient for you, it understands exponential form (use %f)

Comment: Or maybe %lf. (%f for float, %lf for double.) And rather than `scanf()`, use `sscanf()`. Actually, the hard part might be skipping the equation at the start of the line. Parsing the numbers is easy once that initial part has been skipped.

Comment: For "best", research and start with `strtod()`.

Comment: In exponential form or not, is not an important issue when reading `FP` values.

Comment: `strtod()` gives just zeros. I am saying `val = strtod(line, &left_strings);`

Comment: `fscanf ` is not as straight-forward, as it might pick up the digits you got in the equation. 
Is there a way to say give me the LAST three numbers of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to let C read the line reversely, and instruct it to extract the last three figures of that line?

Sure, parse the string and save last 3 successful conversions.
The below does consume `s`.

```
// Return parse count;
int read_last_3_double(char *s, double y[3]) {
  const char *delimiters = " \n\t";
  int i = 0;
  char *token = strtok(s, delimiters);
  while (token) {
    char *endptr;
    double x = strtod(token, &endptr);
    // If no conversion or fails to end with a null character. 
    if (token == endptr || *endptr) {
      // No conversion
      i = 0;
    } else {
      if (i == 3) {
        y[0] = y[1];
        y[1] = y[2];
        y[2] = x;
      } else {
        y[i++] = x;
      }
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
  } // endwhile
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a quick question, what does `&endptr` do when invoking `strtod`. What does `if(*endptr)` mean? does it give true if that pointer is NULL

Comment: @ATK `endptr==NULL`  gives true if that pointer is equal to `NULL`.  That is not the case here.  "what does &endptr do when invoking strtod"  --> See [ref](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod).  `if(*endptr)` --> Take the pointer `endotr`, de-reference it.  Read the `char`, Test if it Is not 0.  ( the _null character_).